# have same id on a two windows

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'd like to use driver.FindElement to locate an element, but code has two identical elements ID on main and embedded windows. How can I locate an element within embedded window?  Thanks!

Comment: I believe the issue is obvious, ID is meant to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

What is "embedded window" in your case? If all windows are in one DOM-tree then you shouldn't expect right behavior of driver.FindElement, because ID should be unique value.

If you mean pop-up window, that you can use driver.switchTo().window(), but I guess that in this case you won't have this issue.

Anyway, try to use xpath, e.g. driver.findComponent(By.xpath("//*[@id='my_unique_id'][2]"))

Comment: If @id is the same in both elements I'd suggest staying away from it. just use xpaths that are more unique (without attaching to the ID)

Answer (score 0):

ID should be UNIQUE.

If your case it is not POP UP window (pop up window solotion provided above ;D ), Instead of finding solution how to cater for the same ID issue, why not follow a good programming practice to **avoid same ID in the same page**?